# Loop + Expression ilegal in evaluator

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Estou fazendo o download de vários arquivos(um atrás do outro) por um *loop*, mas assim que baixa o primeiro, dá *crash*. Segue o *loop*:

```
  for x := StrToInt(version)+1 to StrToInt(version2) do
  begin
    url := baseurl+'/'+IntToStr(x)+'.7z';
    BaixarArquivo(IdHTTP1, url, x);
    if pexit = true then break;
  end;
```

Na linha `if pexit = true then break;` quando coloco o mouse em cima, dá a mensagem:

> Break = Expression ilegal in evaluator.

Como posso evitar esse erro?

Edit: 
Descobri que o erro está dentro da função BaixarArquivo.
Essa linha:

```
downloadedf[high(downloadedf)+1] := IntToStr(Name) + ExtractFileExt(Url);
```

Onde

```
IntToStr(Name) tem o valor de '1'. (String)
ExtractFileExt(Url) tem o valor de '.7z'. (String)
```

E Eu ja tinha declarado:

```
downloadedf : array of string;
```

E em cima da linha do erro:

```
SetLength(downloadedf, Length(downloadedf) +1);
```

Há algo de errado?

Comment: Qual é o valor da variável `pexit`? Se ele realmente é do tipo booleano não faça a verificação desta forma. `if pexit = true` é a mesma coisa que `if pexit`. Ora, `if` espera um `true` ou um `false`, sempre. Se `pexit` vale um destes valores, basta usar a variável, não precisa perguntar se ela vale isto, use o valor já existente. Mas o erro pode ser justamente porque a variável pode estar valendo outra coisa.

Comment: @bigown, Momento algum "pexit" assume outro valor que não seja true ou false, e teste: if pexit then break end; e continua o problema.

Comment: A não ser que existe outra coisa que não aparece no código, então é impossível dar esse erro onde você está apontando.

Comment: Descobri a linha do erro está dentro da função BaixarArquivo, vou editar o post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine que, assim que você declara o array:

```
downloadedf : array of string;
```

E então a nesse momento, o seu array tem Comprimento 0 (`Length(downloadedf) = 0`)

A função `Length()` é usada para obter o tamanho, em um **array vazio é 0** e depois é o tamanho real.

A função `Low()` é usada para obter o menor índice de um array, se ele estiver vazio é -1, caso contrário ele retorna o menor índice que, geralmente é 0

A função `High()` é usada para obter o maior índice de um array, se ele estiver vazio é -1, caso contrário ele retorna o maior índice, o que geralmente equivale a `Length() - 1`

Portanto, depois de aumentar o tamanho do array com o `SetLength`, o `High` já irá lhe retornar o último índice do array em questão

Answer (score 1):

O erro estava em:

```
downloadedf[high(downloadedf)+1]
```

Eu ja estava aumentando o length antes e tentei inserir um valor em um campo inexistente.
Apenas tirei o +1.